# git - updating remotes - Do I need to provide the remotes name?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-remote

I'm writing a script to update several hundred repository remotes due to a url change for our internal code hosting.

Some of these repositories have a different remote name (i.e. different than origin). Have tested not providing the remote name and the updated remote can be pinged but I don't understand the behavior.

1. Is this unusual?
2. What happens if there are 2 or more remotes?

Updating the remotes in a more well defined way is preferred and I've tried using bash to extract the origin name:

What the character between the remote name and address in below?

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@code_hosting_site.com/project_name/repo_name.git (fetch)
      ^^
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That would be a `\t` (tab) character.

Comment: I need to use the remote name to update the same named remote.  I've tried to extract the remote name from this string using `git_remote | awk  '{ print $1 ; }'` and `git_remote%%*\tssh://` Can you advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this normal?

"Normal" is a funny word.  It's hard to define whether this is *normal*.  It's a bit *unusual* to have one remote and not have it named `origin`, but it's not an *error*, it's just *odd*.

> What happens if there are 2 or more remotes?

That's up to you.  `git remote -v` will list all of them, so it's certainly possible to extract them that way.  You can also use:

```
git config --get-regexp 'remote\..*'
```

to list all of them.  You might even want to add `--local` to make sure that only remotes defined in the local `.git/config` file are listed, in case some crazy user has defined a remote in her global configuration.  (I assume you don't want to attempt to update any such entries.)

Note, too, that each remote can define both a URL and a *push URL*.  These configuration names are case-insensitive, so you should fold case when looking for any `remote.remote.url` and `remote.remote.pushurl` settings "by hand" (if you write your own code to read a `config` file), but you don't need to worry about that when using `git config --get-regexp` or `git remote -v` as those do the case-folding for you.

Hence, an sh or bash script to read through `git config --get-regexp` output might use:

```
# fix - called with URLs that may need fixing. Argument $1 is the
# type (url or pushurl), argument $2 is the remote, $3 is the URL itself.
fix() {
    local urltype=$1 remote="$2" url="$3"
    local newurl

    case $3 in
    ...) newurl="echo $url | sed ...";;
    *) return;;
    esac
    git config "remote.$remote.$urltype" "$newurl"
}

git config --local --get-regexp 'remote\..*' | sort | while read -r lhs rhs; do
    set -- $(echo $lhs | sed 's/\./ /g')
    case $3 in
    url|pushurl) fix $3 "$2" "$rhs";;
    esac
done
```

(One can be a bit fancier in bash; the above works in POSIX sh—although the whole thing is quite untested.  Of course you need to fill in the `...` parts as well.)

In general, remote names and URLs should not have white space in them.  I used quotes above to handle cases where they might.  (The `git remote` command does not let you add a remote with a blank in its name, but does allow white-space in the URL.)  The apparently-useless use of "sort" is to handle extreme cases: if the `.git/config` file is very large, we could attempt to run `git config` to *change* the configuration while `git config --get-regexp` is still reading and printing the *old* configuration.   In practice, it's probably not needed.